# 3 routers on network but my main router repeats Mac address of connected devices

Tags: networking, router

Have three routers on a network

- one router (main router with internet and dhcp enabled with?... ip-192.168.1.1)
- second router connected to it via Ethernet ( dhcp disabled with ip-192.168.1.100 )
- the third as a wireless repeater to first router (dhcp disabled and ip-192.168.1.200) .

the problem I am facing is when a device is connected to The third router it shows the routers mac. the number of devices the number of the same mac address repeated. any way to solve this issue?

Comment: last passage needs sentence correction it seems to be not clear and also not matching title of the question

Comment: I'm not sure the problem here, MAC address do not cross routers, meaning one network to another, but will stay within a subnet regardless of the device your communicating with. It sounds like the third router is not configured correctly and without more information we cannot tell you why.

Answer (score 0):

I am going by the question title "3 routers on network but my main router repeats Mac address of connected devices"

This is not a problem, This is just how it works

this is happening because main router is the one giving out IP addresses as you have DHCP Disabled and most probably 2nd and 3rd routers are forwarding all the requests to main router.